# Inputing a date from console in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the time and date system working for today, tomorrow and for a set date. Now I want to create some sort of Console.Read for the system so that you can input any date and receive the corresponding day.

```
    static void date()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
        Console.WriteLine("Today's date is {0}\n", now);

        DateTime currTimeAndDate = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Today's time and date is {0}\n", currTimeAndDate);

        DateTime tomorrow = currTimeAndDate.AddDays(1);
        Console.WriteLine("Tomorrow's date will be {0}\n", tomorrow);

        DateTime then = new DateTime(1995,4,28);
        Console.WriteLine("I was born {0}\n", then.DayOfWeek);
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue.....\n");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void inputDate()
    {            
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem precisely? How to input a DateTime? If all else fails, input a string and then use `Convert.ToDateTime` on it.

Comment: Within the static void inputDate I want to grab something from an input such as
'code'
 static void inputDate()
    {

        DateTime year;


        Console.WriteLine("|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|");
        year = Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date using a MM/DD/YY format");
        Console.ReadLine(year + then.DayOfWeek)

      
    }

Comment: So implement that code and then tell us if it worked or not.  If not, tell why not and what errors/exceptions you are receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a console application, I would recommend using the TryParse method, as follows.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a date: ");
DateTime userDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userDateTime))
{
     Console.WriteLine("The day of the week is: " + userDateTime.DayOfWeek);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("You have entered an incorrect value.");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to be able to have the user to input the dates. You could have them input a month, day and year separately, like so:

```
Console.Write("Enter a month: ");
int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter a day: ");
int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter a year: ");
int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

DateTime inputtedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

If you want, you could have them enter an actual date:

```
Console.Write("Enter a date (e.g. 10/22/1987): ");
DateTime inputtedDate = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Keep in mind that these are examples. In a real program, you should check to make sure the values entered are real. Also, instead of `DateTime.Parse()`, you could use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to be able to allow the user to enter the date in a custom format.

Comment: Whilst the code works, was similar to something I had originally before getting frustrated and deleting it, it doesn't print out what day (ie: friday) it is corresponding to the date.