# Convert all char array except 2 and 5 to int

Tags: c#, arrays, tryparse

I have tried to convert the char to integers however it doesn't let me convert those due to cannot convert from 'char' to 'system read-only span char 'error.. what can I do?
I am new to programming.

CODE:

```
using System;

namespace Bird Sighting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int answer = 1;

            while (answer != 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*** Welcome to Ornithological Conservation Logging ***");
                Console.WriteLine("Make a selection from the menu below:");
                Console.WriteLine("1.Enter a bird sighting ");
                Console.WriteLine("2.List sightings for a specific species");
                Console.WriteLine("3.List all sightings");
                Console.WriteLine("4.Exit");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your selection(1 - 4):");

                // creating all arrays for input
                string[] species = new string[1000];
                string[] Log = new string[1000];
                int[] birdSeen = new int[1000];
                // creating small template// 
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                int.TryParse(input, out answer);
                // using a while loop to repeat the program until the input is 4\

                if (answer > 0 && answer < 5) // in this one i am delimitng the range of the selection, (n
                {
                    if (answer == 1) // This will activate the first option
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the species observed:");
                        string speciesName = Console.ReadLine();
                        while (speciesName.Length == 0) // First obtain a value name and do not proceed until we have one
                        { // this loop will run until they enter atleast one character
                            Console.WriteLine("You must enter a species name -- try again.");
                            speciesName = Console.ReadLine();

                           
                            for (int i = 0; i < species.Length; i++)
                            {
                                if (species[i] == null)
                                {
                                    species[i] = speciesName;

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Now that we have a valid name proceed and get the date
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the date of the observation:");
                        string date = Console.ReadLine();
                        
                        

                        char[] dataLog = date.ToCharArray();

                        int[] logData = new int[1000];
                        
                       
                        if ((dataLog[2] == '/' && dataLog[5] == '/'))
                            

                            {
                            int[] numbah;
                            if (int.TryParse(dataLog[0],out numbah))
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Input error...");
                                Console.WriteLine("Enter the date of the observation:");
                                date = Console.ReadLine();
                                
                                dataLog = date.ToCharArray();


                            }

                        
                        // We won't stop until we get a date


                        for (int i = 0; i < species.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (Log[i] == null)
                            {
                                Log[i] = date;

                            }
                        }



                        // we got a date tgeb we proceed to the number of birds
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of birds:");
                        string num = Console.ReadLine();
                        int number = 0;
                        
                        // when this executes and fails it will break back up to the loop that encloses this
                        while (!int.TryParse(num, out number))
                        // we have need the number of birds
                        {

                            
                                Console.WriteLine("You must enter a number  -- try again.");
                                num = Console.ReadLine();
                            
                            

                            
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                        // we got it, we want to save the data




                        // u need get array length become a insert array index and to extend array size


                        // use the insert array index to assign new data to array


                        // did you learn about how extend array size? like Array.Resize you can do it






                    }
                    else if (answer == 3)
                    {
                        int lenght = species.Length;
                        

                        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(species[i]);
                            Console.WriteLine(Log[i]);
                            Console.WriteLine(birdSeen[i]);

                        }
                    }





                    // 2 and 3
                    /**
                     * u can use the for-loop to print array information or use the while
                     */

                    // example - i give you example u can figure out how do it the example includes how to 

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while (speciesName.Length == 0)` do you understand what you are trying to do here? According to your code `speciesName` is a `string`, not an `array`.

Comment: for parsing date check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42075554/inputing-a-date-from-console-in-c-sharp I think it is better than parse it manually